# Getting exact day values per month, between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions

I am trying to get the amount of days in a month, between 2 dates. So this would ideally look like

```
Month | Days
 Jan  |  5
 Feb  |  28
March |  5
```

The dates need to come from a table that looks like this -

```
Name | Age | Address   | AddressStartDate| AddressEndDate 
Steve| 19  | randomAdd | 2018-01-26      | 2018-03-05
Steve| 21  | randomAdd | 2018-01-26      | 2018-03-05
```

The issue that I am coming across is that I could have multiple steves in this table with the exact same start and end date.

I would ideally not like to have to make a calendar table, and I found a way round this, by using -

```
Declare @dtFrom date 
Declare @dtTo date


select @dtFrom = 2018-01-26
      ,@dtTo   = 2018-03-05

select 
    year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month],  
    count(*)
from 
(
    select top(datediff(d, @dtFrom, @dtTo)) dateadd(d,  row_number() over 
(order by (select null)), @dtFrom) dt
    from sys.columns) q
    group by year(dt), month(dt
)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

but I cannot work out how I can get these separated. Is there anyway I can get these in 1 table?

I currently have approximately 1500 rows, that I would need to reproduce this data for!

Comment: What does your final result look like?  One set of months for *all* rows?  Or the amount for each of the rows?

Comment: What if the dates span more than one year?

Comment: the ideal result is a list of names in the y axis and a list of months - year in the x axis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path, you just need to use a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50),[Age] int,[Address] varchar(50),[AddressStartDate] date,[AddressEndDate] date)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Steve',19,'randomAdd','2018-01-26','2018-03-05')
,('Steve',21,'randomAdd','2018-01-26','2018-03-05')

Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Month=DateName(MONTH,D)
                     ,Days = count(*)
                 From (
                        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[AddressStartDate],[AddressEndDate])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[AddressStartDate]) 
                         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                      ) B1
                 Group By Year(D),DateName(MONTH,D)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - Updated for NULL EndDate**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Month=DateName(MONTH,D)
                     ,Days = count(*)
                 From (
                        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[AddressStartDate],IsNull([AddressEndDate],GetDate()))+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[AddressStartDate]) 
                         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                      ) B1
                 Group By Year(D),DateName(MONTH,D)
             ) B
```

> **Final Edit  -- Concat Year to Month**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Month=concat(DateName(MONTH,D),'-',year(D))
                     ,Days = count(*)
                 From (
                        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[AddressStartDate],IsNull([AddressEndDate],GetDate()))+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[AddressStartDate]) 
                         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                      ) B1
                 Group By Year(D),DateName(MONTH,D)
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks John, for some reason, im getting a 'A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value.'

Comment: @samsmith perhaps you have a NULL date or EndDate is less than BegDate

Comment: @samsmith See EDIT - Updated for NULL EndDate.  Here we use IsNull(EndDate,GetDate())

Comment: I also think it could be something to do with the fact that the column datetime and not date. My bad.

Comment: @samsmith Should not matter.  It would still work with datetime or date.   You may have some bogus data.  Select * from YourTable where EndDate<StartDate  Then try Select * from YourTable where StartDate is Null

Comment: Got it, thanks! Any way I can get the year to append to the month? So for example if Steve has lived in the property for 3 years, im returning april | 30, potentially 3 times.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect.

Comment: @samsmith Happy to help  :)

Comment: Can I just ask what we're doing inside the spt_values table? Just for my future knowledge! Thnaks

Comment: @samsmith Using that to create an ad-hoc tally or numbers table.  Any table of adequate size will do.